# How to use clone() in status bar notification? can i clone an incoming notification?

Tags: android, notification-listener

I am building a listener service where i want to list all the incoming notifications using listener service. for that i need to use clone in order to clone the notification and display it in listview. I don't know how to use clone() in status bar notification. could someone help me out on that?

Comment: Hey, can you add some information on what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have used Listener Service to get all the data using sbn object. I want to clone the notification